# How to find mode but adds a score board?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function that gives multimodal data.

The data is the results of multiple simulations of a model predicting which part of a 4-part cycle we are currently in: Early Cycle, Mid, Late1, Late2. It works as intended (except it does not ignore NaN, which I also dont know how to fix), but I am trying to add a scoreboard.

If Simulation 1 says we are in Early cycle, I want to give some leeway to Late2 and Mid, the cycles that come before and after Early, respectively. To do this, I want to add 1 to Early (since that is what Simulation 1 says), and then add 0.5 to Late2 and Mid. Then, the final result would be whoever has the highest count, instead of taking regular mode. How and where would I add this to my function already?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Simulation1': ['Early', 'Early', 'Mid', 'NaN'], 'Simulation2': ['Late2', 'Late2', 'Late2','NaN'],'Simulation3': ['Early', 'Early','Early','Mid'], 'Simulation4': ['Mid', 'Mid','Mid', 'NaN'],'Simulation5': ['Late1', 'Late1', 'Late1','NaN'],'Date': ['2019-01-01','2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2022-01-01']}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df.set_index('Date')

# Finding Multimodal data
def find_mode(x):
    if len(x) > 1: #
        #Creates dictionary of values in x and their count
        d = {}
        for value in x:
            if value not in d:
                d[value] = 1
            else:
                d[value] += 1

        if len(d) == 1:
            return [value]
        else:
            # Finds most common value
            i = 0
            for value in d:
                if i < d[value]:
                    i = d[value]

            # All values with greatest number of occurrences can be a mode if:
            # other values with less number of occurrences exist
            modes = []
            counter = 0
            for value in d:
                if d[value] == i:
                    mode = (value, i)
                    modes.append(mode)
                    counter += mode[1] # Create the counter that sums the number of most common occurrences

            # Example [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
            # 2 appears twice, 3 appears twice, [2, 3] are a mode
            # because sum of counter for them: 2+2 != 5
            if counter != len(x):
                return [mode[0] for mode in modes]
            else:
                return 'NA'
    else:
        return x
mode = []
for x in df.itertuples(index = True):
    m = find_mode(x)
    mode.append(m)

final = pd.DataFrame(mode).set_index(df.index)
```

Current Output:

```
-------
|Date|0|
------------------
|2019-01-01|Early|
------------------
|2020-01-01|Early|
------------------
|2021-01-01|Mid  |
------------------
|2022-01-01|NaN  |
```

Desired output once 0.5 additions are implemented:

```
df1                                df2
 -------                           --------------------------------
|Date|0|                           |Date      |Early|Mid|Late1|Late2|
------------------                 ---------------------------------    
|2019-01-01|Early|                 |2020-01-01|  3  |2.5| 2   | 2.5| 
------------------                 ---------------------------------
|2020-01-01|Early|                 |2021-01-01|  3  |2.5| 2   | 2.5|
------------------                 ---------------------------------
|2021-01-01|Mid|                   |2022-01-01| 2.5 | 3 | 2.5 | 2  |
------------------                 ---------------------------------
|2022-01-01|Mid|                   |2022-01-01| 0.5 | 1 | 0.5 | 0  |
```

Comment: presumably you call the function with `find_mode(df)` ?   And if so the return is this: `['Simulation1', 'Simulation2', 'Simulation3', 'Simulation4', 'Simulation5']`

Comment: Ah! thank you for catching that, There were actually 5 lines of code at the very end that i forgot to include that would fix this. give me a moment

Comment: no problem.  post a comment when it is updated...

Comment: the last element of what you refer to as `df1` is `NaN` whereas you have got `Mid`.  Also i note that the `df1` dataframe is multiindex.  did you want this ?

Comment: @D.L yes, In the `df`, the last row contains 3 `NaN` s and 1 `Mid` and thus the function does not recognize i do not want these `NaN` values. I just want `Mid`. Also, I did not realize it was a multiindex. how would i fix that?